# How do I animate a smooth transition between all colours in the RGB spectrum?

Tags: animation, materials, shaders

[image]

I want to shade a lightbar. It should have a smooth RGB Transition like in this video at the beginning:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBNohDeo8XI

With a color ramp it would take to long to add like one million colors and with the RGB Circle you have white as a color with in, what I don't need.

Here is a example of a lamp but it also should moving like smoke or something like that, just a smooth transition don't know how to describe that

Comment: Hello :). Please, add an image into your question, so we know exactly what are you trying to achieve. Printscreen of the right video frame should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that's the setup you wanted. By adjusting/animating value node you can achieve effect close enough to what I've seen in the video (or you can just use 'Hue Saturation Value' node input itself). You can adjust look of the gradient by changing texture scale (in the Mapping node), texture interpolation (in texture node itself) and by adjusting colors in the color ramp (for better look I recommend you to use HSV mode (with any sub-option) in the color ramp).

[image: Setup screenshot]

Have a good day!